# JavaScript array reduce() accumulator is empty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am splitting a word and converting each individual element to morse code. However, the return value is empty. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
        wordTransformed = word.split("").reduce((total, letter) => {
            currentLetterIndex = alphabet.indexOf(letter);
            total + morseAlphabet[currentLetterIndex];
            return total
        },"");

        console.log(wordTransformed);
```

Comment: The statement `total + morseAlphabet[currentLetterIndex];` does not do anything.

Comment: please close as typo. `+` vs `+=`

Comment: Understood, it was simply a typo.

Comment: @DanielPahor Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

```
total + morseAlphabet[currentLetterIndex];
```

You're looking for

```
total += morseAlphabet[currentLetterIndex];
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_assignment.asp